# Which encoding to use in App.Config?

Tags: c#, encoding, configuration-files

Following `config` file causes error because of `&` in 'url' value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="url" value ="http://www.example.com/?user=admin&password=1234"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The question is which encoding to use for `key/value` in a `config` file ? (i.e Url Encoding ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an XML file.  As such, you must XML-escape all reserved characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="url" value ="http://www.example.com/?user=admin&amp;password=1234"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Programmatically you can perform this type of escaping using the `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method.  Yes, its name suggests HTML specific encoding, but in my experience this is equivalent to XML escaping.

Comment: Which class in .NET has XML-escape utilities ? VisualStudio editor doesn't replace reserved characters automatically.

Comment: @Xagron, answer enhanced to include your question.